# Android build Layout for all device

Tags: android, android-layout, android-gui

it is possible to build layout (ex: menu) 
that will use coordinates system pt

I need to build menu for game and I need to set all fields on same positions on every screen size

if screen will be big it must be scale everything on the layout and same on small screen size

like this:

[image]

can you provide some example for it?

Answer (score 1):

The following is a list of resource directories in an application that provides different layout designs for different screen sizes and different bitmap drawables for medium, high, and extra high density screens.

```
res/layout/my_layout.xml             // layout for normal screen size ("default")
res/layout-small/my_layout.xml       // layout for small screen size
res/layout-large/my_layout.xml       // layout for large screen size
res/layout-xlarge/my_layout.xml      // layout for extra large screen size
res/layout-xlarge-land/my_layout.xml // layout for extra large in landscape orientation

res/drawable-mdpi/my_icon.png        // bitmap for medium density
res/drawable-hdpi/my_icon.png        // bitmap for high density
res/drawable-xhdpi/my_icon.png       // bitmap for extra high density
```

This has been taken from http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

If you sort your xml files this way, Android itself figures out what file to choose depending on the screen size of the device.

While designing the desired layout, you can opt for Relative Layout which usually sticks to its attributes such as `alignParentBottom`, `alignParentTop`, `alignParentRight`, `alignParentLeft` to name a few.

I hope this solves your issue, although I'm not clear what you're talking about when you say "coordinates system pt"

Comment: I need to build only 1 layout with 1 size bitmaps because it will make increase my apk file

Comment: pt
Points - 1/72 of an inch based on the physical size of the screen.

Comment: If you don't/can't stick to 9 patch as Pratik says, then I don't think there's any other way but to stick to what I've mentioned. You possibly can't support just one size bitmap on all screens. If you do, then the resolution will be lost. As far as layout is concerned, it will be the same for all the screens. Only thing is that you've to place it in different folders, and just optimize it for different screens.

Comment: why? android can't scale bitmaps? when I use android:layout_weight it scale with all screen size but I need also to rescale positions also

Comment: If you want to rescale your items that way, then use android:layout_width = "x dp", where x is an integer. This trick usually works with screens of all sizes. I can't really comment much on bitmaps as I myself don't have good amount of knowledge on bitmaps.

Answer (score 1):

create the image with 9-patch so no need to save the images for different density like hdpi,mdpi etc. it will adjust with control as you define the size or you can save images with different size into the hdpi, mpdi with same name and by runtime in device it will get the appropriate images as per the density available

**edit**

links for 9-patch

http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/draw9patch.html

http://android10.org/index.php/articlesother/279-draw-9-patch-tutorial

http://www.androiddom.com/2011/05/android-9-patch-image-tutorial.html

Comment: I need to build only 1 layout with 1 size bitmaps because it will make increase my apk file –

Comment: then prefer the 9-patch image

Comment: fields on my menu not Buttons, they are ImageButtons and I can't provide it in 9-patch